# What's the most-efficient way to add schema.org metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, schema.org

Is there a more-efficient way to add schema.org metadata than just embedding it in the views?  Is there a way to associate it with the model?

For example, if you have a Hospital model, you'd somehow associate its properties to the relevant [Thing > Place > CivicStructure > Hospital](http://schema.org/Hospital) properties with the model, rather than having to do so in the views.

** edit **

Note that the example in the referenced document embeds schema data in a JSON object.  This leads me to think that it would be useful to have this metadata in the model so it can be represented in various ways (e.g. HTML, JSON).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, just embedding it in the views is the most efficient way.

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't even say unfortunately. This is what views are for. Now if you were storing many hospitals, you could store the properties of each in the model, but you would still display it in the view, maybe with a tag like `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Hospital"><h1><span itemprop="name"><%= @hospital.name %></span></h1><span itemprop="description"><%= @hospital.description %></span></div>`